# Scriptonly cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, httponly

So, basically what I want is the exact opposite of httponly cookies. I want to set a cookie in the browser via JavaScript and be able to retrieve it via JavaScript only. Meaning, that the cookie is *not* sent to the server.

The use case is that the JS application is served from an unencrypted http connection. That means that the cookie is sent to the server unencrypted as well and can be sniffed.

Comment: This is not possible as the cookies are _designed_ to be passed to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is :

- userData in Internet Explorer 5.5 and above.
- Local Shared Object in Adobe Flash Player browser plugin.
- Web Storage in HTML 5 capable browsers

Comment: Users are usually not as liberal with Web Storage as they are with cookies. Web Storage requires the user to explicitly allow the use, where cookies work out of the box (on most systems).